# XMonad/Submap: how do I accept both KeyPressEvent (keyboard presses) and ButtonPressEvent (mouse clicks)?

Tags: button, mouse, keyboard-events, keyevent, xmonad

I wish to modify XMonad.Actions.Submap so that it accepts both keyboard and mouse events (for example, left clicking might be set to do an action, or to abort the submap).  I figured the first step would be to grab and ungrab the mouse buttons:

```
-- | Given a 'Data.Map.Map' from key bindings to X () actions, return
--   an action which waits for a user keypress and executes the
--   corresponding action, or does nothing if the key is not found in
--   the map.
--
--   Executes default action def if the key does not match any of the keybindings.
submapDefault :: X () -> M.Map (KeyMask, KeySym) (X ()) -> X ()
submapDefault def keys = do
    XConf { theRoot = root, display = d } <- ask

    io $ grabKeyboard d root False grabModeAsync grabModeAsync currentTime

    -- ADDED: grab mouse buttons
    -- Does it make a difference whether it's buttonPressMask or buttonReleaseMask?
    io $ grabButton dply button1 anyModifier root True buttonPressMask grabModeAsync grabModeAsync none none
    io $ grabButton dply button3 anyModifier root True buttonPressMask grabModeAsync grabModeAsync none none


    (m, s) <- io $ allocaXEvent $ \p -> fix $ \nextkey -> do
        maskEvent d keyPressMask p
        KeyEvent { ev_keycode = code, ev_state = m } <- getEvent p
        keysym <- keycodeToKeysym d code 0
        if isModifierKey keysym
            then nextkey
            else return (m, keysym)
    -- Remove num lock mask and Xkb group state bits
    m' <- cleanMask $ m .&. ((1 `shiftL` 12) - 1)


    -- ADDED: ungrab mouse buttons
    io $ ungrabButton dply button1 anyModifier root 
    io $ ungrabButton dply button3 anyModifier root 

    io $ ungrabKeyboard d currentTime

    maybe def id (M.lookup (m', s) keys)
```

However, I don't understand how to adjust the code in the middle, to accept either KeyPress or ButtonPress Events. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit: to the best of my knowledge:

1. Replacing `maskEvent d keyPressMask p` with `maskEvent d (keyPressMask + buttonPressMask) p` might be a starting point, but I'm not sure where to go from there.
2. <s>I don't really understand the `fix`.</s>

> Original question:
>
>  It's evident that the code is meant to grab a second key if the first is a modifier.  But since `fix f` yields a value `x` such that `f x = x`, wouldn't `fix` terminate immediately upon a modifier, yielding whatever `nextKey` is at the time?  I also don't get how there is supposed to be a fixed point with a non-modifier key; is `(m, keysym)` supposed to be equal to `nextkey`?

Evaluating the [alternate definition](https://groups.google.com/group/stanford-11au-cs240h/browse_thread/thread/41005683f4479eeb) `fix' f = f (fix' f)`, we get something like:

```
do
  maskEvent d keyPressMask p
  KeyEvent { ev_keycode = code, ev_state = m } <- getEvent p
  keysym <- keycodeToKeysym d code 0
  if isModifierKey keysym
      then (fix' \nextkey -> do ...)
      else return (m, keysym)

do
  maskEvent d keyPressMask p
  KeyEvent { ev_keycode = code, ev_state = m } <- getEvent p
  keysym <- keycodeToKeysym d code 0
  if isModifierKey keysym
      then (do
              maskEvent d keyPressMask p
              KeyEvent { ev_keycode = code, ev_state = m } <- getEvent p
              keysym <- keycodeToKeysym d code 0
              if isModifierKey keysym
                  then (fix' \nextkey -> do ...)
                  else return (m, keysym))
      else return (m, keysym)
```

so I suppose it just does the same thing over and over until `isModifierKey keysym` is `False`.